# Is username@gtld a valid email? i.e. there is no "domain" portion, it is just a TLD for the hostname

Tags: email, hostname

So would username@gtld be a valid email? As a practical example google is purchasing the gTLD "gmail". Obviously they can associate A records with that permitting you to just type `http://gmail/` to access the site. But, are there any *specs* that prohibit them from associating MX records with that as well, allowing folks to give out an alternative address username@gmail?

I ask because I want to make sure our email validator is future proof and technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered my own question. Section 3.4.1 of [rfc5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) which defines a valid email address states:

> addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain
>   [...]
>   domain          = dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain
>   [...]
>   The domain portion identifies the point to which the mail is delivered. In the dot-atom form, this is interpreted as an Internet domain name (either a host name or a mail exchanger name) as described in [RFC1034], [RFC1035], and [RFC1123]. In the domain-literal form, the domain is interpreted as the literal Internet address of the particular host.

"gmail" would be a valid domain and host name and thus someone@gtld is a valid email address.